# Get the value of drop down list that was selected earlier

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, selectlist, selectoption

In my piece of code below, I use select list tag to get user's input for a field of an object. I have a text field type for an object which I am trying to update using a VF page.

```
                <apex:column headerValue="Rating" style="text-align:center;">

                    <apex:outputField value="{!skillreview.skillReview.RatingCopy__c}" rendered="{!NOT(interviewerMode)}"/>

                    <apex:selectList value="{!skillreview.rating}" multiselect="false" size="1" rendered="{!interviewerMode}" id="sl" >
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="N/A" itemLabel="N/A"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>

                    </apex:selectList>

                </apex:column>
```

Description:

Once I hit save on my VF page , I can save the value to the database and I set the interviewerMode variable as false, which would show me `<apex:outputField value="{!skillreview.skillReview.RatingCopy__c}" rendered="{!NOT(interviewerMode)}"/>` and when I click an edit button(custom button which I am able to edit the page) , I make the interviewerMode variable as true, which would show me :

```
                <apex:selectList value="{!skillreview.rating}" multiselect="false" size="1" rendered="{!interviewerMode}" id="sl" >
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="N/A" itemLabel="N/A"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>

                </apex:selectList>
```

The problem: When I hit edit the value of the field is reset back to "N/A" instead of the most recent value of the field that was updated to the field. How can I make the field to retain its value when I use selectList or selectionOption.

Controller:

```
public class InterviewattachmentPDFExtension{

    public Interview__c interview{get;set;}
    public boolean interviewerMode {get;private set;} // make it global, set to true when sending pdf
    public boolean interviewerMode1 {get;private set;}
    public Boolean disabl {get;set;}
    public Boolean disabl1 {get;set;}
    public String rating{get;set;}


    //public SkillReviewWrapperTest ratingskill{get;set;}
    public List<SkillReviewWrapperTest> SkillReviewList{get;set;}
    public List<SkillReviewWrapperTest> SkillReviewList1{get;set;}
     public List<SkillReviewWrapperTest> SkillReviewList2{get;set;}
     public String link {get;set;}
     public List<SelectOption> RatingList{get;set;}
    //public List<skillHelper> evaluationList{get;set;}
    public boolean rend{get;set;}
    public boolean rend1{get;set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardController standrdController;

    public InterviewattachmentPDFExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        disabl1 = true;
        interview=(Interview__c)controller.getRecord();
        standrdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(interview);
        standrdController=controller; 
        interview=[select Job_Application__c,Image__c,Name__c,Interviewer_Feedback__c,Interviewed_Date__c,Interview_Mode__c,Interviewer_Name__c,Hiring_Manager__c, 
                      Years_Of_Experience__c,  Client_Name__c,Business_Unit__c,Recommendations__c,Interviewer_Emp_ID__c,Hiring_Manager_Copy__c,Additional_Interviewer__c,Fitment_Level__c, (select Name,Skill__r.Name,Level__r.Name,Recommended_Level_Description__c,Skill_Level_Description__c,RatingCopy__c from Skill_review__r) from Interview__c where id=:interview.id];

            if(interview.Image__c != NULL){
            String firstSubString = interview.Image__c.substringBetween('<img', 'img>');
            System.debug('First substring: ' + firstSubString);

            String secondSubString = firstSubString.substringBetween('src="', '"');
            System.debug('Second substring: ' + secondSubString);

            link = secondSubString.replace('amp;', '');
            System.debug('Link*************: ' + link);
         }

        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('interviewerMode') == NULL){
            interviewerMode= true;
        }else{
            interviewerMode = Boolean.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('interviewerMode'));

        }

        interviewerMode1 = false;

        initSkillReviews(); 

    }

    public PageReference addErrorMessage() {
    ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Thanks for the FeedBack '));        
    return null;
    }

    private void initSkillReviews() {

        skillReviewList=new List<SkillReviewWrapperTest>();        
        for(Skill_Review__c sr: [SELECT Id,Name,Skill__c,Skill__r.Name,Level__c,Skill_Level_Description__c,Recommended_Level_Description__c,Rating__c,RatingCopy__c,Level_of_Skill__c FROM Skill_Review__c where Interview__c =:interview.id ]){              
            skillReviewList.add(new SkillReviewWrapperTest(sr));
        }

        skillReviewList1=new List<SkillReviewWrapperTest>();        
        for(Skill_Review__c sr1: [SELECT Id,Name,Skill__c,Skill__r.Name,Level__r.Name,Skill_Level_Description__c,Comments__c,Recommended_Level_Description__c,RatingCopy__c,Rating__c,Level_of_Skill__c FROM Skill_Review__c where Interview__c =:interview.id and Skill__r.Non_Technical_Skill__c=false]){              
            skillReviewList1.add(new SkillReviewWrapperTest(sr1));
        }

        skillReviewList2=new List<SkillReviewWrapperTest>();        
        for(Skill_Review__c sr1: [SELECT Id,Name,Skill__c,Skill__r.Name,Level__r.Name,Skill_Level_Description__c,General_Skill_Description__c,Comments__c,Recommended_Level_Description__c,RatingCopy__c,Rating__c,Level_of_Skill__c FROM Skill_Review__c where Interview__c =:interview.id and Skill__r.Non_Technical_Skill__c=true ORDER BY Skill__r.Name]){              
            skillReviewList2.add(new SkillReviewWrapperTest(sr1));
        }
      }    

      public pagereference editInterviewerFeedback(){   
      interviewermode = true;
      return null;
      }


    public pagereference saveInterviewerFeedback(){

        Map<String, String> skillAndLevel = new Map<String, string>();
        for(SkillReviewWrapperTest obj: skillReviewList1 )
        {
            skillAndLevel.put(obj.skillreview.skill__r.Name+obj.rating,obj.rating);
        }

        for(SkillReviewWrapperTest obj: skillReviewList2 )
        {
            skillAndLevel.put(obj.skillreview.skill__r.Name+obj.rating,obj.rating);
        }


        map<String, Id> mapLevelName = new map<String, Id>();
        for(Level__c ratingObj:[SELECT Skill_of_Level__c,Id, Name FROM Level__c WHERE Skill_And_Level__c IN: skillAndLevel.keyset() ])
        {
            mapLevelName.put(ratingObj.Skill_of_Level__c, ratingObj.Id);
        }

        List<Skill_Review__c > updateLevelInSkillReview= new List<Skill_Review__c>();    
        for(SkillReviewWrapperTest obj: skillReviewList1)
        {
            // put the level id in SkillreviewList's Level__c, to be updated in database
            // get the level id using the level name selected by user in picklist stored in SkillReviewList
            obj.skillReview.rating__c = mapLevelName.get(obj.skillReview.Level_of_Skill__c); 
            updateLevelInSkillReview.add(obj.skillReview);
        } 

        for(SkillReviewWrapperTest obj: skillReviewList2)
        {
            // put the level id in SkillreviewList's Level__c, to be updated in database
            // get the level id using the level name selected by user in picklist stored in SkillReviewList
            obj.skillReview.rating__c = mapLevelName.get(obj.skillReview.Level_of_Skill__c); 
            updateLevelInSkillReview.add(obj.skillReview);
        }    

        update updateLevelInSkillReview;

        standrdController.save();
        interviewerMode = false;
        interviewerMode1 = true;
         standrdController.save();
        rend=false;
        rend1=true;
        for(integer i =0 ; i<SkillReviewList1.size();i++){
        system.debug('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&'+SkillReviewList1[i].rating);
        }
        pagereference pr = new pagereference('/apex/InterviewattachmentPDF?scontrolCaching=1&id='+interview.id+'&interviewermode=false');
        pr.setredirect(true);
        return pr;
    }

    public void falsemode(){
    interviewerMode=false;
    }

    public void sendEmail () { 

    OutboundEmails.SendEmailNotification(interview.id);
    }

    public pagereference edit(){
    interviewerMode = true;
    return null;
    }


}
```

SkillreviewwrapperTest:

```
public class SkillReviewWrapperTest{

    public Skill_Review__c skillReview{get;set;}

    public String rating{get;set;}


    public SkillReviewWrapperTest(Skill_Review__c skillReview){

         this.skillReview = skillReview;
         this.rating = skillReview.Rating__c;

    }

}
```

Comment: When you click save on the page, is it a rerender or a total refresh on the page?

Comment: It is rendered when I click the save button. It is not full referesh. I use an id in the pageblock section table and rendered that id when I click the custom button

Comment: Can you post your save method and edit method in your controller, please? Also, can you add a System.debug(skillreview.rating) in your edit method and see the result? I am almost sure it is null. But just want to be sure.

Comment: @LanceShi Pls see the edit

Comment: It could be a problem with the `SkillReviewWrapperTest` constructor. How is `SkillReviewWrapperTest.rating` being populated in a new wrapper?

Comment: Please see the edit. I have included the wrapper class too.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham I see in my view state the wrapperclass variable rating has a 15 digit object id instead of a text like - "5". I have defined level as an object in Salesforce. Does it make sense? I think it is not able to show the value because it is an object id. Makes sense?

Comment: What I found out is correct. What Santanu has suggested is correct. I have to get the string out of the object id. So if the id is 00000..(15 digit) I have to query and get the corresponding value as String "5" and put it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the edit method, assign value from the query like this below:

```
public PageReference editMethod(){
//assign value from database
skillreview.rating = "1";
return null;
}
```

I have shown hard coded value `"1"` here